# Using more than one graphics layer with a FeatureDataGrid

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, c#, feature-layer, wpf

I am wanting to use the FeatureDataGrid to display data. The problem is I have more than one layer that contains data that needs to be displayed.

This is how you use the DataGrid for one layer:

```
private void MyMap_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MyDataGrid.Map = MyMap;
            MyDataGrid.GraphicsLayer = MyMap.Layers[1] as ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.GraphicsLayer;
            MyFeatureDataForm.FeatureLayer = MyMap.Layers[1] as ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.FeatureLayer;
        }
```

This is the XAML for my map:

```
<esri:Map.Layers>
                    <esri:ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer ID="MyLayer" Url="http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer"/>

                    <esri:FeatureLayer ID="Hydrant" 
                                       Url="http://localhost:6080/arcgis/rest/services/CalvertCity_Test_Server/FeatureServer/0" 
                                       Renderer="{StaticResource Renderer_Hydrant}"
                                       MouseLeftButtonUp="FeatureLayer_MouseLeftButtonUp" 
                                       DisableClientCaching="True"
                                       OnDemandCacheSize="0"
                                       Mode="OnDemand"
                                       AutoSave="False"
                                       OutFields="*" />
                    <esri:FeatureLayer ID="WaterValves" 
                                       Url="http://localhost:6080/arcgis/rest/services/CalvertCity_Test_Server/FeatureServer/1" 
                                       Renderer="{StaticResource Renderer_WaterValves}"
                                       MouseLeftButtonUp="FeatureLayer_MouseLeftButtonUp" 
                                       DisableClientCaching="True"
                                       OnDemandCacheSize="0"
                                       Mode="OnDemand"
                                       AutoSave="False"
                                       OutFields="*" />
                    <esri:GraphicsLayer ID="CandidateGraphicsLayer">
                        <esri:GraphicsLayer.MapTip>
                            <Grid>
                                <Rectangle Stroke="Gray"  RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" Fill="#77FF0000" Margin="0,0,0,5" >
                                    <Rectangle.Effect>
                                        <DropShadowEffect/>
                                    </Rectangle.Effect>
                                </Rectangle>
                                <Rectangle Fill="#DDFFFFFF" Stroke="DarkGray" RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5" Margin="10,10,10,15" />
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="30,20,30,30">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding [Address]}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="Black" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </esri:GraphicsLayer.MapTip>
                    </esri:GraphicsLayer>
                </esri:Map.Layers>                
            </esri:Map>
```

I thought about trying to pull the layer for the selected graphic, but I am not sure as to how to do that. If you need any more information or want me to explain further, let me know.

Comment: In this case, do you need to show data on all the hydrants, watervalves, and address results in the map extent, or some combination of those?

Comment: Just the hydrant and watervalves. My feature layers. I need the data to show in the featuredatagrid. Right now it will only show one of the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [FeatureDataGrid](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/runtime-wpf/apiref/index.html?ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Toolkit~ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Toolkit.FeatureDataGrid~_ctor.html) is connected to a single [GraphicsLayer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/runtime-wpf/apiref/ESRI.ArcGIS.Client~ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.GraphicsLayer.html) or [FeatureLayer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/runtime-wpf/apiref/ESRI.ArcGIS.Client~ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.FeatureLayer.html) (which inherits from GraphicsLayer), and uses the attributes to autogenerate column names. Mixing two layers that (probably) have different column names would look confusing on a single table, since some records would fill in some columns, and other records wouldn't. I think that's why the FeatureDataGrid enforces binding to a single layer.

That being said, if you need to show data for two FeatureLayers at the same time, use two FeatureDataGrids, each one bound to a different layer. If you don't have enough room on the screen, I'd recommend a [TabControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tabcontrol%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) with a FeatureDataGrid in each [TabItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tabitem%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Or, you could have a single FeatureDataGrid and a [ComboBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.aspx) or [RadioButtons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.radiobutton.aspx) that let you switch the FeatureDataGrid's GraphicsLayer and FeatureLayer between the two layers.

Comment: The combobox/radiobutton idea is great! I should have thought of that. Do you know if there is a way to tell which feature layer a graphic is associated with when the user clicks on it? I thought about setting the feature layer property of the FeatureDataGrid to the feature layer of the graphic selected, but I am not sure about how to go about that.

Comment: For each FeatureLayer, Create a MouseLeftButtonDown event handler that sets the feature layer property of the FeatureDataGrid to that FeatureLayer. The MouseLeftButtonDown event will trigger when you click on a graphic in the FeatureLayer, and it has access to the graphic you clicked.  MouseLeftButtonDown Event: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/runtime-wpf/apiref/ESRI.ArcGIS.Client~ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.GraphicsLayer~MouseLeftButtonDown_EV.html

Comment: I love when I just look over simple solutions. Thanks again!